# How to add custom markers using react-google-charts GeoChart?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-google-charts

[image]I'm using google charts to display markers on the map. It only has simple circles. I want to use custom images and animations if possible.

```
<Chart
  width={'100vw'}
  height={'100vh'}
  chartType='GeoChart'
  data={[
    ['Lat', 'Long', 'Name'],
    [0, 0, 'test'],
  ]}
  options={{
    region: 'US',
    displayMode: 'markers',
    colorAxis: { colors: ['green', 'blue'] },
    resolution: 'provinces',
    defaultColor: '#555',
    backgroundColor: '#444',
    datalessRegionColor: '#f8bbd0',
  }}
/>
```

```
circle::before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url('../images/man.svg');
  position: absolute;
  color: blue;
  width: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

I don't really understand why it doesn't work. Is this something that can't be done with CSS?

Comment: Can you add the react code as well? Furthermore, what is the result that you are getting, do you see your class being applied at all?

Comment: I added more information, I want the circle to be a custom image.
The class will be updated if I change the fills color for example. But I can't seem to replace the image

Comment: By any chance have you just forgot to add a . in front of the circle class?